# How can I avoid repeating myself when I have Gherkin Scenarios that are similar across different personas?

Tags: bdd, acceptance-testing, gherkin, scenarios

I'm in the process of writing Gherkin Scenarios and am coming across a problem where User Stories apply to multiple Personas in the System we are designing, with subtle differences.

Based on what I've read, the preferred approach is to write Feature files from this perspective:

As a [role/persona]

I want [feature]

So that [benefit]

The problem with this is that I'll end up writing more or less the same scenario for each persona, which is going to end up in a lot of duplication.

To give a specific example, in a Recruitment application, different personas need to be able to view Applicant entities that are registered with the Company. The only difference is that depending on what level of privileges (i.e. what your persona is) you have i.e. Executive level, Regional Manager, Area Manager, Branch Manager, Branch Employee, External Customer, some sort of filtering needs to be applied to the collection of Applicants you can view.

One way of tackling this problem is to orient the Feature / User Story around the Entity (Applicant) rather than the Persona i.e.

**Feature**

As a user of the application (**NB**. Rather than mention specific Persona, we refer to a 'Generic' user persona)

I want to be able to view Applicants

So that I can perform my work duties

**Scenario**

When I request to view Applicants

Then I am to view Applicants that I'm allowed to based on my permissions

This scenario captures the User Story succinctly. However, I would like to test the different use cases i.e. Branch Manager can only view Applicants assigned to his Branch, Area Managers can only view Applicants assigned to his Region, Customer can only view Applicants on work assignment at their Company.

What would be the best way to go about this and do you think the approach of writing User Stories oriented around an Entity rather than a Persona is acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

I would worry less about duplication and focus more on clarity.

If it is important for a stakeholder to see that an Area Manager is allowed to see some stuff and an External Customer is allowed to see some other stuff about the same application then I would express that in Gherkin.

I am sure that these rules will not change often as they are probably at the core of the domain. This means that you will not change them very often. If you need to change them, it must be easy for your stakeholder to understand that.

If you find that there are many variants where the differences are very small, consider a scenario outline to capture all different versions. That could lead to less duplication while still being clear on the differences.

If the changes are of a more of a technical nature and your stakeholder doesn't care, then use  unit tests to capture the implementation and not Gherkin.

But in this case, focus less on duplication and more on creating a common understanding that is easy communicate.

Remember that Gherkin is a communication tool rather than a programming tool. As a communication language, other rules apply than on a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

The "As a [role]" is not about who is a user of the feature but who requires the feature. Mostly, it's some stakeholder who requires features so that the company can benefit and do better business.

In your case, it's about viewing applicants. Different access should be described by more scenarios in the same feature file. However, all your access roles are not crucial to explain the feature. Despite the fact that tools behind the Gherkin can test, Gherkin features and scenarios are more about capturing the idea behind them than cover all possible scenarios. Choose 1-2 the most significant access roles and the rest lay down to lower testing levels, mostly unit tests.

Try to keep in mind the test pyramid where acceptance tests have only a small part of all testing.